# "selection cannot be launched and there are no recent launches" when using pydev/eclipse

Tags: eclipse, pydev

I am getting the above error when launching a python file that worked in the past.  I think I know how this happened but not sure how to fix it.  I have 2 computers dual booting different os and use dropbox to stay synced between them all.  In the past I synced my eclipse workspace with my mac and windows computers this way and everything worked fine(except I would have to change the location of the python interpreter depending on what system I was using).

I started getting the above message after I added a linux(fedora) to share dropbox files.  But my problem is now when I try to update my python interpreter(in windows) it doesn't save my setting.  I can hit autoconfig and it'll find the python path and all the files and I hit apply/okay, but when I go back its all blank.  I'm pretty sure the linux machine messaged my settings up, but I need to develop on all 3 boxes so I need them to be kind of synced.

Wondering how to fix this and if there's another way to do this so I don't have this problem in the future?

update: this def. has something to do with my workspace.  When I change the default workspace to a new folder and set the python interpreter it works.  Still not sure how to permanently fix this(don't want to have to copy code back and forth to new workspaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think an answer of how to share workspace among other enviroments is still very helpful but if anyone is having a simlair problem and just needs to fix it to work quickly here's the solution:

1. go to File, switch workspaces and figure out where your workspace is located
2. Go to that folder and rename the .metadata folder and relaunch eclipse
3. In eclipse everything will be missing, so go to file-->import and import the folder with all your projects(do the root folder of all the projects so you don't have to import each one individually).
4. setup any customizations you had before

This is not the best solution but it works.  Hopefully someone else has a way of preventing this problem from happening in multiple environments.

Answer (score 2):

It seems the preferred way is through F9: http://pydev.org/manual_adv_launch.html

Answer (score 0):

eclipse run as same as what it run last time.
then first time run in this way.
in package explorer (left).
doubleclick res then menu.
then rightclick main menu (name.xml).
frmo menu select run then run as application. 
 and you can run as default in next time(from menu or shortcut).

Answer (score 0):

This problem can often be solved by exiting out of eclipse and restarting (if that happens to be convenient for you).  Changing workspaces midstream can often confuse Eclipse even if PyDev is correctly configured.